# str.split(',', expand = True) is too too...slow, how to enhance the performance?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, split

I have below dataframe :

```
SFDC,SID,MID,ACT
DC02,SID1,GOAL,"view_goal_list"
DC02,SID1,GOAL,"view_goal_card,expand_people_selector_panel"
DC02,SID1,GOAL,"view_goal_list,select_user,click_add_activity"
```

and I want to transform the ACT column to below format:

> SFDC,SID,MID,step1,step2,step3
> DC02,SID1,GOAL,view_goal_list,na,na
> DC02,SID1,GOAL,view_goal_card,expand_people_selector_panel,na
> DC02,SID1,GOAL,view_goal_list,select_user,click_add_activity

here is the code I use, functionally it works, but the performance is too bad when it processing around 5000k records (need several hours.)

```
df.set_index(['SFDC','SID', 'MID'])['ACT'].astype(str).str.split(',', expand = True).rename(columns=lambda x: f"step{x+1}")
```

Can any expert help to provide a solution with quick performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to get it down a bit...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('split.txt')

# 'split.txt' is the example data given in the question copied over and over
print(df.shape)
print(df.head())

(50000, 4)
   SFDC   SID   MID                                            ACT
0  DC02  SID1  GOAL                                 view_goal_list
1  DC02  SID1  GOAL    view_goal_card,expand_people_selector_panel
2  DC02  SID1  GOAL  view_goal_list,select_user,click_add_activity
3  DC02  SID1  GOAL                                 view_goal_list
4  DC02  SID1  GOAL    view_goal_card,expand_people_selector_panel
```

---

Timings for me:

**[172 ms] Current method:**

```
%%timeit

df = pd.read_csv('split.txt')

df = df.set_index(['SFDC','SID', 'MID'])['ACT'].astype(str).str.split(',', expand = True).rename(columns=lambda x: f"step{x+1}")

df = df.reset_index()

# 172 ms ± 2.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**[152 ms] Separate, split and join (bit faster):**

```
%%timeit

df = pd.read_csv('split.txt')

s = df['ACT'].str.split(',', expand=True)

s = s.add_prefix('step_')

df = df.join(s)

# 152 ms ± 1.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**[93 ms] Apply is fast as overall it's in and out of the function quicker:**

```
%%timeit

df = pd.read_csv('split.txt')

def splitCol(s):
    return s.split(',')

s = df['ACT'].apply(splitCol).to_list()

s = pd.DataFrame(s)

s = s.add_prefix('step_')
# if required comment out the above line and instead rename columns 0,1,2,3 etc. to step_1, step_2, etc. rather than zero
#s.columns = ['step_' + str(col+1) for col in s.columns]

df = df.join(s)

# 93 ms ± 1.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**[90.3 ms] Straight str.split().tolist() and join**

Seems the fastest (given ± 3.64 ms).  Slightly skewed because for this block of code `s.columns = ['step_' + str(col+1) for col in s.columns]` is quicker than `s = s.add_prefix('step_')`

```
%%timeit

df = pd.read_csv('split.txt')

def splitCol(x):
    return pd.Series(x.split(','))

s = pd.DataFrame()

s = df['ACT'].str.split(',').to_list()

s = pd.DataFrame(s)

# this seems quicker than s = s.add_prefix('step_')
s.columns = ['step_' + str(col+1) for col in s.columns]

df = df.join(s)

# 90.3 ms ± 3.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Example output:**

```
print(df.head())

   SFDC   SID   MID                                            ACT  \
0  DC02  SID1  GOAL                                 view_goal_list   
1  DC02  SID1  GOAL    view_goal_card,expand_people_selector_panel   
2  DC02  SID1  GOAL  view_goal_list,select_user,click_add_activity   
3  DC02  SID1  GOAL                                 view_goal_list   
4  DC02  SID1  GOAL    view_goal_card,expand_people_selector_panel   

           step_0                        step_1              step_2  
0  view_goal_list                          None                None  
1  view_goal_card  expand_people_selector_panel                None  
2  view_goal_list                   select_user  click_add_activity  
3  view_goal_list                          None                None  
4  view_goal_card  expand_people_selector_panel                None
```

---

If you need the new columns to start at `step_1` rather than `step_0` instead of:

```
s = s.add_prefix('step_')
```

Use:

```
# rename columns 0,1,2,3 etc. to step_1, step_2, etc.
s.columns = ['step_' + str(col+1) for col in s.columns]
```

Comment: Biggest takeaway for me is that `pd.DataFrame(df.ACT.str.split(",").to_list())` is nearly twice as fast as `df.ACT.str.split(",", expand=True)`. That's a really unfortunate performance bug. Seems people have already tried fixing similar things (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35223), but never finished the work. At least `str.split` isn't 400x slower than the Python version anymore (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/10090), I guess :/

Comment: thank you very much for the proposed solution. I tried solution#3 with around 5000k rows * 100k, and it takes around 1 hours, the bottleneck is s=pd.dataframe(s) which nearly takes 58 mins. is it possible to be quicker?

Comment: @cheriemilk Wait: are you computing a `5000k*100k = 500 Gitem` dataframe in RAM that should takes about `4 000 GB` (that even supercomputer nodes does not have yet) ? If so, this seems stupidly huge, especially for a Python code and you probably need to use a totally different approach.

Answer (score 0):

This code is already written to achieve the decent performance using Pandas, there are no loops or lambdas involved.

For testing, I've repeated the same three records to form a DataFrame of 5 million rows.  Wall time for this operation on 5M records is around 10 seconds for me, on a laptop.

As you write that it takes several hours for you, I would guess that you have rows with not just 3 steps, but many more - perhaps hundreds or thousands. If you have few rows with a lot of steps you'll mainly run into memory copy issues, I'd assume.

Then how to solve the issue is not on trying to get more performance out of Pandas (already near the limit), but think how you really want to represent your data. Do you have a few rows with many steps, and lots with few steps, so you have a mainly empty table in the end?

Perhaps look at the distribution of the number of steps by running `df.ACT.str.count(",").describe()` and then decide what to do, for example splitting the DataFrame into groups depending on the number of steps.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Yes. I have lots of rows with lots of steps. 5000k * 100 columns, which is really huge.